# Coerce coefficients of linear regression to 1, 0 or -1

Tags: r, linear-regression, coefficients

I have some columns that combined should give another one. I want to know how this last column is calculated, given that they will only be added or substracted or not used (therefore, 1, -1 and 0).

My idea was to run a linear regression where coefficients can only take one of these three values, but I don't know how to make it possible in R.

Comment: If your result column is a nice linear combination of the other columns, linear regression will easily find that perfect solution - you don't need to help it out by restricting the coefficients.

Comment: Even if it's not perfect, if they data are how you describe, the result should be close enough that  you can easily tell based on the coefficients.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the significant coefficients are far from 1... I guess then that the information on my data is not correct.